# Inject user details as session scoped bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

A while back I came across an example of an elegant way of getting hold of information about the currently logged in user in Spring controllers. But now I can't seem to remember exactly how, and I'm unable to find any examples (most are with SecurityContextHolder or other older ways of doing this). As far as I remember it was something like:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
    @Autowired
    private Principal principal;
```

And then it would inject a different object based on the context (which user was behind the invocation). But I can't exactly recall how it was done, or which object was injected. Can anyone refresh my memory? I'm using Keycloak as IDP.

Comment: You're looking for `@AuthenticationPrincipal` as a request parameter.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I came across that, but it would require taking in a `Principal` as an argument for each method. The method I found earlier allowed me to inject Principal or UserDetails or whatnot as a class level field, leaving the method signatures untouched.

Comment: Don't Do That.™ You're introducing hidden dependencies into your code, and that always ends badly one way or another. If the active principal can vary on each method request (as in the usual case for Spring MVC), then it should be expressed as a parameter.

Comment: Since the bean to be injected was session scoped, it would always contain the active principal. As far as I remember it was clear enough that it was session scoped.